# How to extract string[] from List<MyStructure>

Tags: android, arrays, list

I just would like to extract the "name" attribute of my structure into a string[].

I know there must be a smart solution - but I don't have an idea what to look for.

```
List<MyStruct> myStruct1;

public class MyStruct1 {

    public String name1;
    public List<MyStruct2> myStruct2;
}

public class MyStruct2 {
    public String name2;
    public List<MyStruct3> myStruct3;
}
```

and what I am looking for is

```
String[] names1 = ? the array of all name1 coming from MyStruct1 ?
```

I know the `.toArray` conversion for simple lists, but I don't have an idea how to get it from inside a structure. I would think there is a solution WITHOUT having to loop manually.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am overlooking something, but:

```
String[] names = new String[myStruct1.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < myStruct1.length(); ++i) {
    names[i] = myStruct1.get(i).name1;   
}
```

Or, are MyStruct1 and MyStruct2 subclasses of MyStruct and you only want the names from MyStruct2 objects?

Comment: thanks - I see you are using a loop. I was hoping there is another way similar to objective C that gets all the values without having to loop. (by the way lists have size(), not length())

Comment: What is the problem with a simple loop? What makes you believe the built-in functions aren't doing the same loop?

Comment: there is no "problem" - I just thought there is a "more elegant" way - like in objective C